# Spring invoke method before every method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Is there any way to invoke a method before every method call for a bean?

Im using selenium and cucumber with spring. All the pages are singletons because of this and since I'm using @FindBy annotations I want to invoke PageFactory.initElements(driver, object) every time a page is used.

Using a standard page object pattern, this would be done by invoking it in the constructor.

What I'd like to avoid is to specify in each method the method like so:

```
public void clickThis() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
    ...
}

public void clickThat() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
    ...
}
```

I dont want to return the new page since they will not be able to be shared between features.

Answer (score 6):

Spring has a great AOP support and you can get benefits of it.

What you have to do in order to solve your problem is.

1. Enable aspects in Spring by adding a `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` in your Spring configuration file.
2. Create a simple class and register it as an Aspect.

Source:

```
<bean id="myAspect" class="some.package.MyFirstAspect">
   <!-- possible properties ... for instance, the driver. -->
</bean>
```

The `MyFirstAspect` class. Note that is marked with the `@Aspect` annotation. Within the class, you will have to create a method and register it as a `@Before` advice (an advice runs before, after or around a method execution).

```
package some.package;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MyFirstAspect {
    @Before("execution(* some.package.SomeClass.*(..))")
    public void initElements() {
        //your custom logic that has to be executed before the `clickThis`
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

Comment: Hmm, but I need to reference the actual instance of the class.

Comment: I'm thinking of skipping the @FindBy annotations and use driver.findElement(By selector) on each click instead. Feels like the most "readable" solution.

Comment: No, you're not referencing an actual instance. The annotation does this for you

Comment: What I mean is that the code I want to run needs a reference to the instance. PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)

Comment: Well...you can handle this by injecting a property in the aspect and instead passing `this` to pass the injected property.

Answer (score 0):

As kocko mentioned you could use [aspects](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html).

Beside that: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but do you really need to call initElements with each method-call? Or just when you create your page. In later case I would suggest to create an abstract page where you call your initElements-method and inherit every other page from it.

Comment: The state of the page might have changed since its first creation. For example, a menu has been toggled and to get updated WebElements in the java class I have to use initElements again.